# mozilla box orientation is not working with absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I'm having a problem with orienting box on the mozilla. the similar code works with `-webkit` but not with the `-moz` I have created a fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/BczEF/. if you check this on mozilla then then two divs appear on the vertical axis but my desired result is on horizontal axis. if I remove the the `position:absolute` then it becomes perfect.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the image on Chrome :D - However, have you tried using Display: inline or inline-block with both divs?  'div1, div2 { display: inline; }'

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LloanAlas actually I changed the design a little and included another absolutely positioned div ... so the -moz-orient goes inside the abolutely positioned div which resolved the issue.. but this issue should be discuss as to what is causing it to fail..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the design a little and included another absolutely positioned div ... so the -moz-orient goes inside the abolutely positioned div which resolved the issue.